# Highlight search text with UWP

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, uwp

I'm trying to convert some code from Windows phone 8 silverlight to UWP but there's situation which I do not understand.

Here's the error:
Failed to assign to property 'StyledText.MyControls.TextBlockProperties.StyledText'. [Line: 58 Position: 58]

The error is happening whith bind of the extended property StyledText

First I create a class to extend control property of a TextBlock

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup

Namespace MyControls
    Public NotInheritable Class TextBlockProperties
        Public Shared Function GetStyledText(obj As DependencyObject) As String
            Return DirectCast(obj.GetValue(StyledTextProperty), String)
        End Function

        Public Shared Sub SetStyledText(obj As DependencyObject, value As String)
            obj.SetValue(StyledTextProperty, value)
        End Sub

        Public Shared ReadOnly StyledTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StyledText", GetType(String), GetType(TextBlock), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf StyledText_Changed))

        Private Shared Sub StyledText_Changed(d As DependencyObject, args As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
            Dim tb As TextBlock = DirectCast(d, TextBlock)
            Dim text As String = DirectCast(args.NewValue, String)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(text) OrElse Not Regex.IsMatch(text, "<Run.*?>.*?</Run>") Then
                tb.Text = text
                Return
            End If
            Dim formattedTextBlockXaml As String = "<TextBlock xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" & text & "</TextBlock>"
            Try
                Dim AuxXml = XamlReader.Load(formattedTextBlockXaml)
                'Dim formattedTextBlock = DirectCast(AuxXml, TextBlock)
                Dim formattedTextBlock As TextBlock = TryCast(AuxXml, TextBlock)

                ' detach parsed inlines from the view tree
                Dim inlines = formattedTextBlock.Inlines.ToList()
                formattedTextBlock.Inlines.Clear()

                ' add inlines to the specified text block
                tb.Inlines.Clear()
                For Each inline As Documents.Inline In inlines
                    tb.Inlines.Add(inline)
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
                'IGNORA OS ERROS
            End Try
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

XAML is shown below.....

```
<Page
    x:Class="StyledText.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ext="using:StyledText.MyControls" 

    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="AddressGroups"
                              IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Gray" Width="480">
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="NameTxt" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="28" Foreground="White"/>
                                <!--HERE'S THE ERROR-->
                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"  ext:TextBlockProperties.StyledText="{Binding Address}"  />

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And finally the code behind to populate data:

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
    Inherits Page

    Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        SetItemSource()
    End Sub
    Private Sub SetItemSource()
        Dim source As New List(Of AddressBook)()
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Joe", "Smith", "US", "48579347594")) '1
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Jim", "Johnson", "UK", "3423423423")) '2
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Mary", "Robert", "India", "9384394793")) '3
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Patricia", "James", "France", "9384394793")) '4
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Linda", "Williams", "Italy", "9384394793")) '5
        source.Add(New AddressBook("David", "Jones", "US", "9384394793")) '6
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Elizabeth", "Martinez", "US", "9384394793")) '7
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Richard", "Robinson", "Germany", "9384394793")) '8
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Charles", "Clark", "US", "9384394793")) '9
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Joseph", "Rodriguez", "France", "9384394793")) '10
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Susan", "Lewis", "Italy", "9384394793")) '11
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Thomas", "Lee", "US", "9384394793")) '12
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Margaret", "Walker", "US", "9384394793")) '13
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Christopher", "Hall", "UK", "9384394793")) '14
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Lisa", "Allen", "US", "9384394793")) '15
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Daniel", "Young", "US", "9384394793")) '16
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Paul", "Hernandez", "US", "9384394793")) '17
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Karen", "King", "US", "9384394793")) '18
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Ruth", "Wright", "US", "9384394793")) '19
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Steven", "Lopez", "US", "9384394793")) '20
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Edward", "Hill", "US", "9384394793")) '21
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Sharon", "Scott", "US", "9384394793")) '22
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Brian", "Green", "US", "9384394793")) '23
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Michelle", "Ramos", "US", "9384394793")) '24
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Ronald", "Mason", "India", "9384394793")) '25
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Laura", "Crawford", "US", "9384394793")) '26
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Anthony", "Burns", "US", "9384394793")) '27
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Sarah", "Gordon", "India", "9384394793")) '28
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Kevin", "Hunter", "US", "9384394793")) '29
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Kimberly", "Tucker", "US", "9384394793")) '30
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Jason", "Dixon", "US", "9384394793")) '31
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Deborah", "Mills", "US", "9384394793")) '32
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Matthew", "Warren", "US", "9384394793")) '33
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Jessica", "Nichols", "US", "9384394793")) '34
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Gary", "Knight", "US", "9384394793")) '35
        source.Add(New AddressBook("Shirley", "Ferguson", "US", "9384394793")) '36

        listView1.ItemsSource = source

    End Sub
Public Class AddressBook
    Public Property FirstName() As String

    Public Property LastName() As String

    Public Property Address() As String

    Public Property Phone() As String

    Public Sub New(myFirstname As String, myLastname As String, myAddress As String, myPhone As String)
        Me.FirstName = myFirstname
        Me.LastName = myLastname
        Me.Address = myAddress
        Me.Phone = myPhone
    End Sub
End Class
```

Anyone have a clue of what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I've ran your code, first of all, you may have missed a `<ListView x:Name="listView1">` in your XAML code.

Then, in your `Namespace MyControls`, you should change this code:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly StyledTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StyledText", GetType(String), GetType(TextBlock), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf StyledText_Changed))
```

to:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly StyledTextProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("StyledText", GetType(String), GetType(TextBlockProperties), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf StyledText_Changed))
```

You are wrong here to get the type of your class.
Here is the [sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.setvalue.aspx?cs-save-lang=1) in MSDN

By the way, why you use `DependencyObject` to get the `Text` of `TextBlock`? If you just want to get the `Address` for a `TextBlock`, you can change your code `ext:TextBlockProperties.StyledText="{Binding Address}"` to `Text="{Binding Address}"`. It seems you've used a `UserControl` or `CustomControl` in your project, but I didn't find any use of them. Should this `TextBlock` Control be one of them?